# Return only holiday date list from CRM 2015 calendar using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am new to CRM 2015 and I want to write C# method which connects to CRM and return only holiday date list from calendar like this:

```
List<DateTime> lst = GetHolidayListFromCRM();
......
public List<DateTime> GetHolidayListFromCRM()
{
   IOrganizationService service = GetServiceProxy(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, CRM_URL);

   using (OrganizationServiceContext svcContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service))
   {
       var info = svcContext.CreateQuery("calendar");
       //Some code here for processing and returning only holiday date list
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```csh
List<DateTime> ret = new List<DateTime>();

QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("calendar");
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Business Closure Calendar");
EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

if (ec.Entities.Count != 1) { return ret; }
Entity calendar = ec.Entities[0];
if(!calendar.Contains("calendarrules")) { return ret; }
EntityCollection rules = calendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules");

foreach (Entity rule in rules.Entities)
{
    ret.Add(rule.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("startime"));
    // Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", rule["starttime"], rule["name"]);
}

return ret;
```

Note: It is not possible to access directly calendar rule:

1. http://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/08/calendars-and-expand-calendar-request-in-crm-2013-sp-1/
2. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/185090
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327912.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: thanks for reply. I am getting empty list as rules.Entities always empty

Comment: Try to remove this condition 'qe.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Business Closure Calendar");', whether you get some results. Then the option can be adjusted to another calendar. Also, check if you are connected to the right organization and if it has some holidays defined.

Comment: addition: If you are OnPremise, you can try to inspect directly the database.